# Compare 2 columns and merge rows on match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

New to coding here and trying to make a project. I want to compare two DF, and if any of the rows in the product column matches, I want to copy it over to a new DF. The rows in DF1 and DF2 will not be in the same position. Like I want to compare row 1 DF1 against the entire column in DF2. Is there an easy solution to this?

[image]

Comment: use `pd.merge`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/02/how-to-subset-pandas-dataframe-based-on-values-of-a-column/

You can try:

```
df3 = df1[df1['Product'].isin(set(df2['Product']))]
```

Which gives:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'prod':[1,2], 'ean':[5,6]})
>>> df1
   prod  ean
0     1    5
1     2    6
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'prod':[3,2]})
>>> df2
   prod
0     3
1     2
>>> df1[df1['prod'].isin(set(df2['prod']))]
   prod  ean
1     2    6
```

To explain:

- df1[...] is to filter the rows of df1 based on criterion ...
- I'm using a set() here so it is fast to check whether a row in df1 is in df2's "Product" column

Comment: Worked like a charm. Was really struggling with the .isin...  Another  quick question, is it possible to do a .contains? So row in df1 contains any product from colunm in df2. Like fish cake in df1 and only fish in df2?